# Border arround image in report created in PHP with FPDF

Tags: php, image, report, fpdf

i have added an image in a pdf generated in PHP with FPDF, the problem occurs when i insert an image the image gets inserted at the right location but with an ugly border around it whereas in the actual image there is no border. Another important thing that need to be mentioned here is that i have re-sized it with the FPDF Image() method parameters my code is:

```
$this->Image('report_footer.jpg',10,280,190,8);
```

The border appears only on the top and left side of the image as shown below:
[image: Border Problem in FPDF]

Any idea to get rid of the border arround my image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try providing the image *type* alongwith other parameters. You can also try editing the image to the required dimensions and then give it a try. If that doesn't work you can try using TCPDF with html write and *image* with *border 0* attribute.

Comment: Indeed there was a problem with the image i have edited it with GIMP and now it works perfectly. Thanks for your suggestion.